# TFTP Server - Issue With Threaded Version

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, pthreads, tftp

I created a simple tftp server that only handles read requests (RRQ). Everything was working fine until I started to make a multi-threaded version of the server. In the application, I simply receive requests in the main thread and I then forward the request to a new thread that does the packet analysis. Therefore, I need to forward the socket, the received packet and the sockaddr_in struct that contains the client information to the thread. With that said, I created a struct that holds all of these and forward them to the pthread.

I suspect the problem to be in the struct `clientThread` initialization part and forwarding part; since I'm certain of the correctness of the processing inside `connection_handler`.

Note: You can use the tftp client that comes with linux to test it.

Here's the code I've written so far (Threaded Version). Please compile it with the `-pthread` flag...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>

#define TIMEOUT 5000
#define RETRIES 3

void *connection_handler(void *);

struct clientThread 
{
    int clientSock;
    char buffer[1024];  
    struct sockaddr_in client;
};

int main()
{
    char buffer[1024];
    int udpSocket, client_socket, nBytes;
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr, client;
    socklen_t addr_size;

    udpSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(69);
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    memset(serverAddr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof serverAddr.sin_zero); 

    bind(udpSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));

    while(1)
    {
        memset(buffer, 0, 1024);
        nBytes = recvfrom(udpSocket,buffer,1024,0,(struct sockaddr *)&client, &addr_size);

        // Creating a thread and passing the packet received, the socket and the sockaddr_in struct...
        pthread_t client_thread;
        struct clientThread clientT;
        strcpy(clientT.buffer,buffer);
        clientT.clientSock = udpSocket;
        clientT.client = client;
        pthread_create(&client_thread, NULL, connection_handler, &clientT);
    }

    return 0;
}


void* connection_handler (void *clientThreaded)
{
        char buffer[1024], filename[200], mode[20], *bufindex, opcode;

        struct clientThread *cthread = clientThreaded;
        int udpSocket = cthread->clientSock;
        strcpy(buffer, cthread->buffer);
        struct sockaddr_in client = cthread->client;

        bufindex = buffer;
        bufindex++;

        // Extracting the opcode from the packet...
        opcode = *bufindex++;

        // Extracting the filename from the packet...
        strncpy(filename, bufindex, sizeof(filename)-1);

        bufindex += strlen(filename) + 1;

        // Extracting the mode from the packet...
        strncpy(mode, bufindex, sizeof(mode)-1);

        // If we received an RRQ...
        if (opcode == 1)
        {
                puts("Received RRQ Request");
                struct timeval tv;
                tv.tv_sec = 5;
                char path[70] = "tmp/";
                char filebuf [1024];
                int count = 0, i;  // Number of data portions sent
                unsigned char packetbuf[1024];
                char recvbuf[1024];
                socklen_t recv_size;

                socklen_t optionslength = sizeof(tv);
                setsockopt(udpSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &tv, optionslength);

                FILE *fp;
                char fullpath[200];
                strcpy(fullpath, path);
                strncat(fullpath, filename, sizeof(fullpath) -1);
                fp = fopen(fullpath, "r");
                if (fp == NULL)
                    perror("");

                memset(filebuf, 0, sizeof(filebuf));


                while (1)               
                {
                        int acked = 0;
                        int ssize = fread(filebuf, 1 , 512, fp);
                        count++;
                        sprintf((char *) packetbuf, "%c%c%c%c", 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00);
                        memcpy((char *) packetbuf + 4, filebuf, ssize);
                        packetbuf[2] = (count & 0xFF00) >> 8;
                        packetbuf[3] = (count & 0x00FF);

                        int len = 4 + ssize;

                        memset(recvbuf, 0, 1024);
                        printf("\nSending Packet #%i", count);
                        sendto(udpSocket, packetbuf, len, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &client, sizeof(client));

                        for (i=0; i<RETRIES; i++)
                        {
                            int result = recvfrom(udpSocket, recvbuf, 1024, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &client, &recv_size);

                                if ((result == -1) && ((errno == EAGAIN) || (errno == EWOULDBLOCK)))
                                {
                                    sendto(udpSocket, packetbuf, len, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &client, sizeof(client));
                                    printf("\nRetransmitting Packet #%i", count);
                                }

                                else if (result == -1)
                                {
                                   // Handle Error
                                }

                                else
                                {
                                    acked++;
                                        printf("\nReceived ACK For Data Packet #%i", count);
                                        break;
                                }
                    }


                        if (acked!=1)
                        {
                            puts("\nGave Up Transmission After 3 Retries");
                                break;
                        }

                        if (ssize != 512)
                            break;
                }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here's my code for the Non-threaded version...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>
#define TIMEOUT 5000
#define RETRIES 3

int main()
{
    int udpSocket, nBytes;
    char buffer[1024], filename[200], mode[20], *bufindex, opcode;
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr, client;
    struct sockaddr_storage serverStorage;
    socklen_t addr_size;

    udpSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(69);
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    memset(serverAddr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof serverAddr.sin_zero); 

    bind(udpSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));

    while(1)
    {
        memset(buffer, 0, 1024);
        nBytes = recvfrom(udpSocket,buffer,1024,0,(struct sockaddr *)&client, &addr_size);
        printf("%s",buffer);
        bufindex = buffer;
        bufindex++;

        // Extracting the opcode from the packet...     
        opcode = *bufindex++;

        // Extracting the filename from the packet...
        strncpy(filename, bufindex, sizeof(filename)-1);

        bufindex += strlen(filename) + 1;

        // Extracting the mode from the packet...       
        strncpy(mode, bufindex, sizeof(mode)-1);

        // If we received an RRQ...
        if (opcode == 1)
        {
                puts("Received RRQ Request");
                struct timeval tv;
                tv.tv_sec = 5;
                char path[70] = "tmp/";
                char filebuf [1024];
                int count = 0, i;  // Number of data portions sent
                unsigned char packetbuf[1024];
                char recvbuf[1024];
                socklen_t recv_size;

                socklen_t optionslength = sizeof(tv);
                setsockopt(udpSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &tv, optionslength);

                FILE *fp;
                char fullpath[200];
                strcpy(fullpath, path);
                strncat(fullpath, filename, sizeof(fullpath) -1);
                fp = fopen(fullpath, "r");
                if (fp == NULL)
                        perror("");

                 memset(filebuf, 0, sizeof(filebuf));


                while (1)
                {
                        int acked = 0;
                        int ssize = fread(filebuf, 1 , 512, fp);
                        count++;
                        sprintf((char *) packetbuf, "%c%c%c%c", 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00);
                        memcpy((char *) packetbuf + 4, filebuf, ssize);
                        packetbuf[2] = (count & 0xFF00) >> 8;
                        packetbuf[3] = (count & 0x00FF);

                        int len = 4 + ssize;

                        memset(recvbuf, 0, 1024);
                        printf("\nSending Packet #%i", count);
                        sendto(udpSocket, packetbuf, len, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &client, sizeof(client));

                        for (i=0; i<RETRIES; i++)
                        {
                                int result = recvfrom(udpSocket, recvbuf, 1024, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &client, &recv_size);

                                if ((result == -1) && ((errno == EAGAIN) || (errno == EWOULDBLOCK)))
                                {
                                    sendto(udpSocket, packetbuf, len, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &client, sizeof(client));
                        printf("\nRetransmitting Packet #%i", count);
                                }

                                else if (result == -1)
                                {
                                        // Handle Error
                                }

                                else
                                {
                                        acked++;
                        printf("\nReceived ACK For Data Packet #%i", count);
                                        break;
                                }
                        }

                         if (acked!=1)
                        {
                            puts("\nGave Up Transmission After 3 Retries");
                            break;
                        }

                        if (ssize != 512)
                                break;
                }
        }
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Without locking of any kind on the socket ? How on earth can you expect this to work. The socket is a shared resource if you do it multithreaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You loop listening on port 69 but the actual data transfer will be carried out from a different randomly selected port (please read RFC 1350).
Then your main loop must create a new thread for every new transfer, this new thread should receive a structure containing the path of the file to serve, the destination IP/port, the randomly selected local port, etc.

Something you **must** consider when passing a structure pointer to a thread is the memory supporting the structure.
In your case

```
     struct clientThread clientT;
```

is dinamicaly created in the stack and of-course the structure is "discarded" when the block of code goes out of scope (in your case on every loop) that means you are passing a pointer to "soon to be garbage" to the just created thread.

I recommend using malloc/free when passing structures to just created threads.

Finally your main thread (dispatcher) should maintain a structure taking into account all the created threads and their status. This is necessary to detect dead threads or when needing to close the main program when there are transfers in progress.

As you can see implementing a server even for a simple protocol like TFTP is not really easy.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection handler is wrong here because there is no locking whatsoever on the socket that you pass to each thread.

Most servers that are udp based are in fact not forking multiple threads. TCP  servers can do it , because with each accept you get a new socket that can be delegated to a new thread that won't be used by any other thread.

But for udp, you are basically using the same socket for all your threads and this is not ok. If you were to provide protection on the socket you can make it work, but you will lose the benefits that you are trying to obtain by making it multithreaded.

Comment: Sorry: I have downvoted this answer; 1) I consider "Most servers that are udp based are in fact not forking multiple threads." is plain wrong when implementing i.e a TFTP server or a delayed DHCP Server, etc. 2) The problem on locking the socket is not the real issue here as it is wrong to consider that the OP will be using the same socket for all the threads; please read RFC-1350.

Comment: @Pat, I think 1 is a matter of opinion. The udp servers that we implement are single threaded. It is even mentioned in Stevens. 2. you see in the code that he is in fact using the same socket. Bottom line, there are a lot of issues with that code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041291/problems-implementing-a-multi-threaded-udp-server-threadpool applies here too

Comment: @Philip; 1) It is not a matter of opinions; you just cannot implement a TFTP server w/o multithread, you cannot implement a delayed DHCP server w/o multithread. 2) you pointed out a socket sharing issue when you should've said that the OP was in fact mistakenly interpreting the TFTP standard. The socket sharing issue is naturally avoided when  RFC 1350 is correctly implemented

Comment: we agree to dissagree on all points :-) it is not because you give an example of 2 that most udp servers are mutlithreaded all of a sudden. I was correct with my multithreaded issue and wrong using of the shared socket. I only looked to it from a different angle than yours. But your answer is better than mine I don't have problem to admit.

Comment: btw thanks for explaining the downvote. At least I can learn from the experience, with just a downvote, I wouldn't have known your reasoning.

Comment: Philip there's a false association in your answer and the quoted link saying that UDP and multithread do not mix well and that's is just wrong. VOIP traffic is also a clear example. I hope you can see it. See ya.